# How can i invoke a method in a different controller including parameters using mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I'm new to developing web applications and most importantly new to mvc. I'm trying to navigate from one view to another controller action including parameters. I have the below code in my currently displaying view:

```
<p>
<a asp-controller="Working_set" asp-action="Create">Create new Working set</a>
</p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail tile tile-medium">
        <a asp-controller="SelectedWorking_set" asp-action="index">
            <h2>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                <input name="workingSetID" type="hidden" value="@item.Working_setID" />
            </h2>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

How can i use the Working_setID in the controller SelectedWorking_set below:

```
[Route("SelectedWorking_set")]
public class SelectedWorking_setController: Controller
{
    private FlightmapContext _context;

    public SelectedWorking_setController(FlightmapContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("Index")]
    public IActionResult Index([FromBody]int workingSetID)
    {
        //return View(_context.Project.ToList());
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass input name to your controller method like below example;

```
<input name="workingSetID" type="hidden" value="@item.Working_setID" />
```

here "workingSetID" name we need to pass your controller method, Suppose your method name is "Index" then you need to write like this in your controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string workingSetID)
{
   //Code here
}
```

like this you will get "Working_setID" value in your controller method. And also you need submit button to post this value to controller.